# Killing an Oozie workflow from java

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

So i've been playing around with the Oozie java api, all fine and dandy until i've hit the following problem. While trying to run the following java code:

```
OozieClient oc = new OozieClient(OOZIE_URL);

Properties conf = oc.createConfiguration();

conf.setProperty(OozieClient.APP_PATH, PATH_TO_WF);


String jobId = oc.run(conf);

while(oc.getJobInfo(jobId).getStatus() == WorkflowJob.Status.PREP){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

oc.kill(jobId);
```

This fails with the following exception:

```
E0508: User [?] not authorized for WF job [JOB_ID_GOES_HERE]
```

I've been able to find some related issues on google, though the ones i noticed were only related to the command line oozie client.

My main question is that considering you can run an Oozie workflow from java as another user by simply adding:

```
conf.setProperty("user.name", "user123");
```

Is there something similar that can be done with killing a workflow ?

Answer (score 1):

Use AuthOozieClient and set system user.

```
OozieClient oc = new AuthOozieClient(OOZIE_URL);
System.setProperty("user.name", userName);
client.kill(jobId);
```

Comment: Are you able to resolve the issue.I am still getting the same exception.Let me know if you are able to resolve the same and if yes what is the code change